# Master MySQL5.6 - Slave MySQL 8.0 slow relay log reads

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-8.0

We have 4 Servers, 1 Master and 3 Slaves. 2 slaves are on 5.7 version and working perfectly, whereas 3rd slave that is mysql 8 (test version). 3rd slave imported dump in 1 hour when other took 3-4 hours, but it cannot catch up with master and from 5000 seconds behind he went to 200K seconds behind in 3 days. Also binlogs are fetched perfectly without any delay from master. Problem seems to be with reading the relay logs, but not sure what exactly cuases it. In process list I see `waiting for handler commit` changing to `Opening tables` doing insertion from relay log and then going back to `waiting for handler commit`. MySQL is idle, not reading any relay logs for some seconds, then again reads. Server has 40CPUs and 250GB Memory. Server it self is idle. Server running on CentOS 7.6

Comment: From your Slave 8.0 server, additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW SLAVE STATUS`.